# Convergence of Trigonometric Dirichlet series

Tags: convergence-divergence, dirichlet-series, trigonometric-series

Can it be proved that the following series converges for some integer value of $s$?

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^s|\sin(n)|}$$

If so what value(s) of $s$ would it converge for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It certainly converges for $s>7.61$. [Salikhov](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrrationalityMeasure.html) proved that $|\pi - p/q| \geq q^{-7.61}$ for all integers $(p,q)$ with $q$ sufficiently large. So $|q \pi - p| \geq q^{-6.61}$ and, since $p$ and $q$ must be basically proportional for this to be at all close to true, $|p - q \pi| \geq p^{-6.61}$.

For any $p$, choose $q$ to be the integer so that $(q-1/2) \pi < p < (q+1/2) \pi$. Since $|\sin x| \geq |x-q \pi| (2/\pi)$ for $x \in ((q-1/2) \pi, (q+1/2) \pi)$ (draw a graph), this shows that $|\sin p| \geq (2/\pi) p^{-6.61}$. We have
$$\left| \frac{1}{p^s \sin(p)} \right| \leq p^{-s+6.61}$$
so this converges for $s > 7.61$.

The general assumption is that the truly order of irrationality of $\pi$ is $2 + \epsilon$, in which case this argument shows that the sum converges for $s > 2$.

I would actually guess that the sum converges all the way up to $s>1$, but I don't have an argument right now.

---

This question isn't going to have a truly easy answer. Let $a_i$ be a very rapidly growing sequence of integers (I'll decide how fast later.) Let $n_i = a_1 a_2 \cdots a_i$. Let $\theta = \pi \sum \frac{1}{n_i}$. I claim that we can make $\sum \frac{1}{n^s \sin (\theta n)}$ diverge for all $s$.

Observe that $\theta n_i$ is extremely close to an integer multiple of $\pi$: The error is essentially $\pi/a_{i+1}$. So $1/|\sin(\theta n_i)|$ is as large as $a_{i+1}/\pi$. If we choose $a_i$ to grow so fast that $\lim_{i \to \infty} a_{i+1}/n_i^s = \infty$ for any $s$, then the terms of $\sum 1/(n^s \sin(\theta n))$ won't go to $0$, so the sum won't converge.

So, in order to prove your result, you need to know that $1/\pi$ isn't extremely closely approximated by rationals. This is essentially the same as Salikhov's result (although it would be good enough to use [Mahler's result](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Pi.html), which is the same bound with the exponent $20$.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this I upvoted, what I really need is a very simple proof that there exists such an integer. It doesn't matter how large the integer is, or how good the bound is either. Do you know where I could find that? If you want I could create another question and accept your answer here also.

Comment: Give me a little time to dig around in the archives. I saw a question like this before, with a very clever answer...